# Is there any library / jQuery plugin to create form from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, post, serialization

I would like to send some POST data (which I have in Javascript object) using Javascript and then show the result page.

My first thought was to use AJAX jQuery `$.post()` method, because I could directly pass on my data object into this method. But `$.post()` just return the result instead of showing it (and `$('html').html(result)` seems to be problematic - Javascript scripts are loaded again).

So I have figured out the best way could be to send hidden form using `.submit()`. Does anyone know some library that serialize Javascript object into HTML form? Or, at least, into URI component.

Some array work and recursion would be nice, e.g.:

`{numbers: [5, 72]}` => `numbers[]=5&numbers[]=72` or

`{user: {id: 5, name: 'Pepa'}}` => `user[id]=5&user[name]=Pepa`

Thx.

Comment: Do you want the page to be reloaded on submit or do you want it to make an actual ajax call and display the data?

Comment: [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: use pure json to do it, simple and easy

Answer (score 1):

You could encode it into json in javascript and the decode it in PHP using json_decode

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Json == Javascript object.  Create a Json object, post it: problem solved :)  Here's a good [Json Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp)

Comment: Thanks, JSON is a good idea. But I've just found `jQuery.param()`, which is exactly the thing I was looking for. I will create hidden form, hidden input, put result of this function into the input and send the form via `.submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a MVVM framework with Angular.js or Knockout.js.
In knockout.js, for example, you can create a template form and send and receive objects in json, very simple!